# Adding numbers read from a file to a totalAmount initialized to 0 giving an unexpected result

Tags: java

I have a small homework application that writes random numbers from 5 to 77 to a text file, and then a separate application that reads the file and totals the numbers.

Here is my code for writing the numbers to the text file...

```
Random r = new Random();
    int min = 5;
    int max = 77;
    int[]randomNumbers = new int[1000];

    try
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myTextFile.txt")), true);
        for(int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            randomNumbers[i] = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            pw.println(randomNumbers[i]);
        }

    }
    catch(IOException io){}
```

Here is my code for reading the file and totalling the amount...

```
int totalAmount = 0;

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader buffy = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myTextFile.txt"));
        String s;

        while((s = buffy.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
            totalAmount += number;
            System.out.println(totalNumbers);

        }



    }
    catch(IOException io){}
}
```

The output however starts with **29633** and displays numbers all the way to **42328**

Why do I get this result... just trying to understand the wrong part of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to print out each number from the file, or only print out the total?

If you need to print each number, the `while` loop in your **total** application should look like this...

```
    while((s = buffy.readLine()) != null) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
        totalAmount += number;
        System.out.println(number); // changed the variable here
        }
```

However, if you only need to print out the final result, you need to move the `System.out.println()` line outside the `while` loop (and still change the variable to **totalAmount** ...

```
    while((s = buffy.readLine()) != null) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
        totalAmount += number;
        }
    System.out.println(totalAmount); // changed the variable here, and moved it outside the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `totalNumbers` instead of the variable you accumulated your values into (`totalAmount`), which is an uninitialized variable. Its contents are undefined and unpredictable.

```
System.out.println(totalNumbers);
// Should be
System.out.println(totalAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks.Even after correcting this little mistake I still get the high numbers. I am expecting that it should start with a random number such 40 for example and the adding it to the totalAmount with a new random number being added to the totalAmount with the next loop.